# fsck from initramfs console with 'f' key not working

Tags: ubuntu, bash, grub, fsck, initramfs-tools

My ubuntu laptop is dropping to initramfs console due to file system errors. I need to do 'fsck' manually. But the letter 'f' is not working in my keyboard. Right now I can't get a new keyboard. Is there any shell tricks through which I can somehow run the fsck command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0. If you are running full bash (including `printf`), you can do

   ```
   "$(printf '\146')sck"
   ```

   Well, d’oh; that doesn't work if you can’t type the `f` in `printf`.
1. Since your question focuses on the initramfs console,
   I assume that you have some way of operating
   when the system is fully up and running;
   perhaps by copy and paste. 
   Do

   ```
   type -a printf
   ```

   to find the binary executable for `printf`. 
   (It is probably in `/bin` and/or `/usr/bin`.) 
   Then do

   ```
   ln -s /bin/printf /bin/printt
   ```

   as root, using the appropriate directory. 
   Then, in the initramfs console, do

   ```
   "$(printt '\146')sck"
   ```

   (which uses the link you just created). 
   You can use a different name if you prefer; e.g., `p` or `pt`.

   You may need to repeat this every time you get a distribution update. 
   It might be better to put the link into a directory
   that is in your `PATH` in the initramfs console,
   but that is not overwritten by distribution updates
   (e.g., something with "`local`" in its name).
2. Alternatively, do

   ```
   "$(echo -e '\0146')sck"
   ```

   You may need to experiment with this to get a variation that works
   (because `echo` is not as standardized as `printf` is). 
   For example, `/usr/bin/echo` might work better than the builtin `echo`,
   and you might not need the leading zero.

Comment: But how does one type the `f` in `printf`?

Comment: @user1686 D’oh! I’ve fixed it.

Comment: I just realized that the `$''` quoting syntax (e.g. `$'\164sck'` or `$'\x66sck'`) actually works in the busybox-ash shell (used by most initramfs consoles), so it might be the most convenient approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can type `/sbin/?sck`. But perhaps the reason `f` doesn’t work may be found.